# Converting FullCalendar Horizontal Resource Agenda View from v3 to v6

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3, fullcalendar-6

I am upgrading from FullCalendar v3 to v6 and need help converting the horizontal resource agenda view from V3 to V6. In v3, resources were displayed horizontally across the top, but I can't find an equivalent in v6. Any guidance on how to achieve this in v6 would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

```js
var getDaysInMonth = function () {
  var d = new Date();
  var year = d.getYear();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
};

var getMonthDay = function () {
  var d = new Date();
  return d.getDate();
};

var getMinTime = function () {
  var days = getMonthDay() - 1;
  var time = "-" + days + ".00:00:00";
  return time;
};

var getMaxTime = function () {
  var days = getDaysInMonth() - getMonthDay() + 1;
  var time = days + ".00:00:00";
  return time;
};

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'resourceView',
  selectable: false,
  nowIndicator: false,
  allDaySlot: false,
  views: {

    resourceView: {
      type: 'agendaDay',
      minTime: getMinTime(),
      maxTime: getMaxTime(),
      slotDuration: '24:00:00',
      slotLabelFormat: [
      'MMMM YYYY',
      'D'],

      buttonText: '' } },


  selectable: false,
  nowIndicator: false,
  allDaySlot: false,
  resources: [
  { id: 34470, title: 'Auditorium A' },
  { id: 344701, title: 'Auditorium B', eventColor: 'green' }],

  events: [
  { id: '1', resourceId: 34470, start: '2023-06-15T01:00:00', end: '2023-06-15T11:59:00', title: 'event 1' },
  { id: '11', resourceId: 34470, start: '2023-06-15T01:00:00', end: '2023-06-15T11:59:00', title: 'event 2' },
  { id: '111', resourceId: 34470, start: '2023-06-15T01:00:00', end: '2023-06-15T11:59:00', title: 'event 3' },
  { id: '111', resourceId: 34470, start: '2023-06-15T01:00:00', end: '2023-06-15T11:59:00', title: 'event 4' },
  { id: '2', resourceId: 344701, start: '2023-06-15T01:00:00', end: '2023-06-15T11:59:00', title: 'event 5' },
  { id: '4', resourceId: 34470, start: '2023-06-15T01:00:00', end: '2023-06-15T11:59:00', title: 'event 6' },
  { id: '5', resourceId: 34470, start: '2023-06-15T01:00:00', end: '2023-06-15T11:59:00', title: 'event 7' }] 
});
```

```css
#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.fc-event{
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.10.0/fullcalendar.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="calendar"></div>

<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.10.0/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.10.0/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar/3.10.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

FullCalendar v3 horizontal resource agenda view:
https://codepen.io/asifkhankadiwala/pen/JjedaMG

Comment: What sort of help? What is the problem? Have you actually tried anything? Have you read the documentation for v6? Have you read any of the upgrade guides? (Start with v3 to v4, then look at each subsequent one, to trace what happens to the various features.) https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view documents this view in v6.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/upgrading-from-v3#vertical-resource-view

Comment: P.S. This view is not called "horizontal resource agenda view" and [never has been](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3#toc). Maybe that's one reason why you're having trouble finding information about it. Try to use the real terminology that fullCalendar uses to describe the functionality, rather than inventing your own :-)

Comment: Your Question "What sort of help? What is the problem?"
Ans: I am upgrading from FullCalendar v3 to v6 and need help converting the horizontal resource agenda view from V3 to V6.

I have checked "vertical-resource-view" of v4 and v6 but both support only one day at a time.
I want similar like example i have created in v3 with month view (resouce name on top and dates on left side).
I am searching for solution from last 2 days then i finaly posted here. Hope you have anything to help.

Comment: `but both support only one day at a time`...no, they don't. Just like before, you can use day or week views, or a custom duration. That hasn't changed.

Comment: `I want similar like example i have created in v3 with month view`...you've done that by mangling a "day" view and subverting its timescale, which you are using to represent the days. This is messy and not the way fullCalendar is intended to be used. I'd guess you can still do it in v6 in much the same way, but you'd need to apply the similar code to make a mess of the vertical timeline. Again, have you actually _tried_ anything? It's unclear what you want from us. We'll _help_ you with a specific issue in code you've actually tried, but we don't research and write it all for you. See [ask].